# Visual Studio Database Project removing user after every Publish?

Tags: sql-server, database-project, dacpac

I have a **Visual Studio database project**, every time I publish it to SQL Server, it removes the **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE** Login user.

After every publish I then have to go back into SQL Server Management Studio and add the user again via the User Mapping tab.

Does anyone know why this is and how I can stop it from doing this?

[image]

I currently have this in the dbo -> Security folder, but we have other project that also just have this and work fine with the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.

[image]

Comment: Is the user included in the Visual Studio Database Project in the Security section?

Comment: I've update the question with a screenshot of the current folder structure, am I looking in the right place?

Comment: That is SSMS, it shows what is currently present in the database itself. Is the login present/defined in the VS project ?

Comment: Another question: do you want to manage database permissions through the project? They can, will, and should vary by environment (Dev, QA, Production, all should have their own separate and distinct logins/permissions). Here, we do not manage the permissions through the project, but rather configure the project to IGNORE these settings.

Comment: @PhilipKelley yes I know the screenshot is SSMS as I mentioned, I was showing that I had to add it after each publish. If you mean under the Security folder which I have provided a screenshot of, no, so you would expect to see that user granted access under the Security folder in a .sql file? Is this the default what happens when I publish, that it wipes the users? How do you configure the project to IGNORE these settings? thanks

Comment: Did you set the publish option to ignore users/permissions? That usually helps for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managing settings like this can be difficult to figure out, set up, and get consistently correct, as there are a lot of situations and project settings to deal with. Start with the following, then poke around, do some experiments--it can be done.

When publishing a database from VS, you should get this screen. Clicking on Advanced...

[image]

Will get you this dialog (note that I am showing the SECOND tab)

[image]

Scroll down and select the "Do Not Drop Users" checkbox.

You would need to do this every time you publish the database--but fortunately you can save a publish "Profile"--back on the first screen, via the "Save Profile" buttons. We add these profiles in their own "Publish" folder in the project (tagged with Build Action = None) for ease of access and use.

The (very) irritating thing is, there are a LOT of settings and checkboxes buried in here, and a number of them impact database security and permissions settings. I'm reasonably certain this is the only one you'll need to deal with, but there are a lot of other settings and variations to consider. Whatever you hit, odds are there's a setting in here that, once you figure it out, can address it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this, useful to know for sure as I am by no means an expert using database project. This was not a problem for me but think your answer will be much more useful for people, so will mark it as the answer, my problem would seem to be specific to the project due to post deployment scripts... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was specific to the project and how it has been done.

I compared a post deployment script of another project and the one I was having problems with had extra bit at the top of the sql file where it was removing users based on names provide as publish parameters. This was not in the other project.

```
exec sp_executesql @sql
set @sql = 'DROP USER IF EXISTS [$(AdminLoginName)]'
exec sp_executesql @sql
set @sql = 'DROP USER IF EXISTS [$(QALoginName)]'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Removing this stops it from removing my said user, I don't honestly know why this would be in there if the other project works without it. I don't like database projects!, I find them clunky and hard to work with compares to a nice numbered migration like dbup or fluent migrator, but it's what this company use!

Appreciated the help from people, it sounds like there are some publish options to ignore users.

Comment: SSDT (Database projects) can take a LOT of getting used to. They are state-based deployments, as compared with migration-based. I have used both, and each has advantages and disadvantages. These days I prefer state-based, but it's like a 65/35 preference.